# NoMethodError (undefined method `fetch_value' for nil:NilClass) in RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

**Table Name in SQL : road_ratings**

**Route:**

`get '/roadRatings', to: "road_ratings#index"`

**Controller: road_ratings_controller.rb**

```
class RoadRatingsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @data = RoadRating.all
        render json: @data
    end

end
```

**Model: road_rating.rb**

```
class RoadRating < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Upon running the above API, I get the error in rails server logs

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `fetch_value' for nil:NilClass):
```

And following error on browser

`NoMethodError in RoadRatingsController#index`

However when I run the query `SELECT`road_ratings`.* FROM`road_ratings`LIMIT 1` generated in rails logs on SQL, I get the correct result

**Rails Logs:**

```
Started GET "/roadRatings" for ::1 at 2016-10-04 23:55:57 -0400
Processing by RoadRatingsController#index as HTML
  RoadRating Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `road_ratings`.* FROM `road_ratings` LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `fetch_value' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/road_ratings_controller.rb:4:in `index'


  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (5.6ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.4ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (23.1ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (16.7ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.7ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (39.4ms)
```

Rake Routes:

```
Kartiks-MacBook-Air:Mayor_project kartik$ rake routes
     Prefix Verb URI Pattern            Controller#Action
            GET  /                      home#default
    streets GET  /streets(.:format)     streets#index
            GET  /street/:id(.:format)  streets#show
   potholes GET  /potholes(.:format)    potholes#index
roadRatings GET  /roadRatings(.:format) road_ratings#index
```

Comment: Can you have a look at your server logs (either `log.development.log` or in your terminal window) and give us a few more lines on either side of the error that you're seeing? (It will help us pinpoint exactly where the error is coming from). Edit your question and add the data that, don't add it to comments because code-formatting is dreadful and makes it unreadable :)

Comment: Let us know how you're running that API. Are you doing it via browser address bar or are you clicking a link?

Comment: @MarsAtomic I am running API on the browser bar. http://localhost:3000/roadRatings

Comment: @kartik Can you try hitting the endpoint with curl? `curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:3000/roadRatings`. May we also see your routes.

Comment: @TylerFerraro Just posted the Routes in the question.

Comment: @TylerFerraro The curl returns the HTML of the same error the browser shows

Comment: @kartik Please provide index view

Comment: pls paste the complete model code.

Comment: @kartik did you overwrite the initialize method or modify the attribute setters/getters in your model? Please post your model code.

Comment: are you sure you're not calling `fetch_value` anywhere? Search your whole directory for the string.